# What are best practices for combining PHP and Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a MySQL/PHP ticketing system application for a fairly big company which will possibly have between 1000-2000 users. This is my first real enterprise application and so I really want to make sure I do things properly based on best practices. I am not what you would call a seasoned developer. I know how to write code and make it work but i've never had a mentor or anyone to correct my work so I have no idea if the way I do things is good or bad... or even ass backwards.

We have 4 levels of access for the system and so the application needs to read these from the users session. My partner did the back end DB programming and i'm in charge of front-end interface. I've spent the last 6 months writing small tools using pure Jquery and so I have become a big fan of it, and find that I can do things really quickly with it. For interface work I love it.  However, session management can only be done in PHP afaik.

That's not necesarily a problem since I can include bits of JS and PHP on the same page though I prefer not to if I don't have to. For instance, my login page is just JS/HTML which makes an ajax request to a PHP login web service. Any time I can delegate processing tasks to PHP I prefer to write a service which I can use in an AJAX call.

If I have to deal with sessions however, I don't think i'm going to be able to do that. Or can I? I'm interested in hearing from you professionals out there on what you feel are the best practices related to this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sessions are based on cookies which are sent with AJAX requests. So sessions will work with AJAX requests.

Comment: Did you consider just using a pre-written application like http://osticket.com/

Comment: @Waygood But the fun part is coding it!

Comment: Yes it is :-D. Love it myself too! Just dive in and do it, get your hands dirty. We learn from our mistakes so make a few and become a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should you some PHP frameworks and check how they handle JS.

I recommend [Yii framework](http://yiiframework.com).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't let JavaScript be aware of any sessions. Permission control is done in PHP as the page is being created; you can choose to hide parts of the page based on access control. That way the interface doesn't have to bother about permissions at all, it works with what's currently on the page.

PHP typically propagates sessions using cookies (I would recommend using the HttpOnly option); those are transparently used by JavaScript in AJAX calls, so your sessions should just work as expected.

In the case that you must support browsers that do not support (or rather, reject) cookies and you want to use AJAX, you need to find other ways, e.g. let PHP generate a piece of JavaScript that will initialize the session id so that the script can pass it along via POST, GET or special HTTP headers when you do AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

If by *session management* you mean access control, then as long as you get the information you need through AJAX calls etc (don't really see any other way...), then the server-side should be able to handle access and such fine. If you make use of the common status codes (400, 401, 403, etc) on the server side, then you can just make sure jQuery handles those in a good way and things should be easy.

- Give me the tickets I'm allowed to see. Sorry, you need to login, 401.
- I'm logged in now. Ok, here is the list of tickets available to you.
- I want to see ticket number 56. Sorry, you're not allowed to see that, 403.
- I want add this comment to ticket number 42. Sorry, you're missing something in your input, 400.

Just remember to, on the server side, *always* check access wherever appropriate. Don't assume the user has access if the user should have access. Check it :)

Anyways, it depends on what you mean by *session management*, so I could be way off here...